# Extract version attribute from the CRL

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate

Facing issues while extracting the version 2 as shown in the image

`openssl crl -inform DER -text -noout -in CRL`

[image: Need Version 2 in the output]

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def extract_crl_version(crl_file_path):
    with open(crl_file_path, "rb") as file:
        crl_data = file.read()

    crl = x509.load_der_x509_crl(crl_data, default_backend())

    crl_version = crl.version

    return crl_version

crl_file_path = "path/to/crl.crl"
crl_version = extract_crl_version(crl_file_path)
print("CRL Version:", crl_version)
```

This is not working for me

**ERROR:** `crl_version = crl.version AttributeError: '_CertificateRevocationList' object has no attribute 'version'`

Comment: It's true, there is no attribute `version` in a `cryptography.x509.CertificateRevocationList` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no attribute version. in this url:
https://cryptography.io/en/3.4/x509/reference.html#x-509-crl-certificate-revocation-list-object

try print len(crl) and

```
for r in crl:
    print(r.serial_number)
```